# How can I add a new item to a EntitySet Using EF4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I tried to add some new items to entityset by creating new instance and add it using `AddTo` method then I called `SaveChanges()` method to update my database but no new recode had been added.

```
foreach (var newitem in newItemsList)
{
      if (newitem.SomeValue > 0)
      {
          dbcontext.AddToMyEntityType(newitem);
      }
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

but when I used `MyEntityType.CreateMyEntityType()` method all new items are saved into my database

```
foreach (var newitem in newItemsList)
{
      if (newitem.SomeValue > 0)
      {
          MyEntityType _newEntity = MyEntityType.CreateMyEntityType();//I passed the required parameters
          dbcontext.AddToMyEntityType(_newEntity);
      }
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

why????

should I use `Create` method or there is another ways to do that?

**Edit**

I forget to mention that `newitem` have a navigation property(foreign key for a parent table) and I set this property with an a correct parent ID

Comment: And what is AddToMyEntityType and CreateMyEntityType?

Comment: @VikciaR :) `AddToEntityTypeName` and `CreateEntityTypeName` like `AddToPersons` and `CreatePerson`

Comment: And what is dbcontext and mycontext?

Comment: sorry, it is `ObjectContext` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a difference between `newItem` and `_newEntity` on property level. `CreateMyEntityType(...)` doesn't do more then `new MyEntityType` and setting the properties you pass in. `CreateMyEntityType(...)` encourages to set properties for all required fields. Perhaps you set a required property (like a string) which isn't set in `newItem`. `SaveChanges` in your first example throws actually an exception because of the missing required field but you hid this exception (by `try { ... } catch {}` or something). Check in the debugger if `SaveChanges` passes without exception.

A hypothesis.

Comment: I set all properties and used debugger to check if `SaveChanges()` throws any exception but no exceptions occurred.also nothing saved into my database.

Comment: @Miroprocessor: Can you check before you call `SaveChanges` if there are actually objects in `Added` state in the context, like so: `dbcontext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).ToList();`

Comment: I checked `Added` state, my `dbcontext` contains the added items but still not saved into my db. I forgive up and will use `Create` method.any way thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

In first part you are not initializing the object of entity set
This will work if you initialize the object of entityset by doing  some thing like this

```
 foreach (var newitem in newItemsList)
 {
  if (newitem.SomeValue > 0)
  {  
      MyEntityType obj = new MyEntityType
      {
       value1 = newitem.somevalue,
       value2 = newitem.someothervalue
      };

      myContext.AddToMyEntityType(obj);
  }
 }
  dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

In your seceod part you have deifned the enititySet in which u wany add new object and also initilazes the object of the entiity by this

```
 MyEntityType _newEntity = MyEntityType.CreateMyEntityType();

  myContext.AddToMyEntityType(_newEntity);
```

Here you are telling that add _newEntity to my MyEntityType
AddToMyEntityType is a depreceated method for adding a new object to MyEntityType Entity Set..

Comment: ohh, what does newitem contain of MyEntityType ??Try the edited code

Comment: @Miroprocessor: If newItemsList is the collection of MyEntityType than it shouuld wok the way you were doing it.... check the code by replacing var from MyEntityType

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var newitem in newItemsList)
{
      if (newitem.SomeValue > 0)
      {
          dbcontext.AddObject("entity set name", newitem);
      }
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
var entitySet = dbcontext.CreateObjectSet<item type>();
foreach (var newitem in newItemsList)
{
      if (newitem.SomeValue > 0)
      {
          entitySet.AddObject(newitem);
      }
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I tried these solutions but didn't work, I wonder I have to use `Create` method?!!!!!

Comment: @Miroprocessor are you sure your `newitem` type is part of EF model?

Comment: YES. `newItemsList` is `List<MyEntityType>` and `MyEntityType` is part of EF model.

Comment: I forgive up and will use Create method.any way thanks for your interest